# Numerical double integration with functional values

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I DO NOT have the function. But functional values. I have to integrate these values over a domain. I have a rectangular domain. I used trapezoidal equivalent by taking average of 4 values then multiplying by the elemental area. But I think there is too much error. Is there another way to do this with more accuracy? I have searched the web, didn't come across any method.

Comment: You could refine the grid using, for example, cubic interpolant ([interp2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp2.html) in Matlab).

Comment: Have you tried triangulating, instead of trapezoiding. Given a cloud of points, you should be able to triangulate your domain and then just integrate the individual tetrahedra. (Area under the surface). How do you know that you have 'too much error' and how would you know that that error has been reduced?

Comment: I am reproducing results from a paper. The results are not matching.